# Tabela Expansível

Tags: javascript

Nesse script a baixo https://jsfiddle.net/gatkzgtw/4/ tenho uma tabela que se expandi ao clicarmos na linha. ao se expandir ele me mostra uma segunda tabela.
o problema é que o script esta se repetindo nessa segunda tabela inpedindo de mostrar todas as linha, nessa segunda tabela se clicarmos só ai e mostrada o resto das linha, como posso fazer para o script só funcionar a expanção na primeira tabela?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O melhor era fazeres isso com CSS e dares as classes no servidor quando geras esse HTML. Mas para responder à tua pergunta e fazer isso via JavaScript sugiro algumas mudanças.

Usa `thead` e `tbody`, especialmente neste caso em que tens tabelas dentro de tabelas os seletores ficam mais certeiros. Usa também seletor de descendente direto `>` que evita encontrar outras `tr` dentro da tabela que está dentro de uma `tr`.

Assim podes usar:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#report > tbody > tr").hide();
    $("#report > tbody > tr:even").addClass("odd").show();

    $("#report tr.odd").click(function () {
        $(this).next("tr").toggle();
        $(this).find(".arrow").toggleClass("up");
    });
});
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gxr47dqr/

e para fazer parte disso no CSS podes fazer assim: https://jsfiddle.net/gxr47dqr/2/

Comment: Perfeito isso mesmo, só uma duvida... porque você acha melhor fazer em CSS?

Comment: @FabioHenrique o CSS é mais rápido que o JavaScript e assim poupas linhas de código e processamento. Por exemplo essas tabelas vão estar sem nada escondido até o browser correr o JavaScript, quando que se tivesses esses esconde/mostra no CSS ele carregava logo com a página.

Comment: Você teria alguma modelo de exemplo?

Comment: @FabioHenrique juntei um exemplo na resposta

Comment: Muito bom vou fazer por este ..... Valeu irmão