# Tabela Expansível Com reversão de Expanção

Tags: javascript

Nesse script a baixo https://jsfiddle.net/gxr47dqr/ tenho uma tabela que se expande ao clicarmos na linha. Como posso fazer com que expanda uma por vez.

**Exemplo:**

```
  clico na primeira linha  "**expande**"
   se
  clico em outra linha     **também se expande mas fecha a anterior**
```

a inteção é so deixar uma linha expandida por vez

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faz o que fôr possivel com CSS. A parte de esconder e mostrar pode ser feita com classes de CSS, como tinha falado [na outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/92001/129).

CSS

```
#report > tbody > tr:nth-child(even) {
    display: none;
}

.abrir {
    display: table-row !important;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var escondidas = $("#report > tbody > tr:odd");
    $("#report > tbody > tr:even").click(function () {
        escondidas.removeClass('abrir');
        $(this).next("tr").addClass('abrir');
        $(this).find(".arrow").toggleClass("up");
    });
});
```

Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/f9kwbh6e/

Comment: Isso Mesmo Show...